# Create Docker for Wso2 DAS

Tags: docker, wso2, complex-event-processing

There are documents of reference for create a DockerFile for wso2 CEP or DAS?

My arquitecture is Ubuntu 14.04, DAS 3.0.1 and Java 8.

Is posible make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/DF110/Building+Docker+Images to create docker images.

Answer (score 0):

This is my DockerFile, I tried and run perfect:

```
# USAMOS JAVA 8 PARA SUBIR SERVICIOS DE DAS 301
FROM java:openjdk-8

# AUTOR: RHRG
MAINTAINER ROBY HERNAN RUBIANO

# VARIABLES DE AMBIENTE
ENV WSO2_BUNDLE_VER=3.0.1
ENV WSO2_BUNDLE_NAME=wso2das-${WSO2_BUNDLE_VER}
ENV WSO2_FOLDER_NAME=wso2das02a
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr

# DESCARGAMOS DAS
RUN wget --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download" -U testuser -q -P /opt http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/data-analytics-server/${WSO2_BUNDLE_VER}/${WSO2_BUNDLE_NAME}.zip

# UNZIP DAS Y COPIAR EN CARPETA DE TRABAJO
RUN unzip /opt/${WSO2_BUNDLE_NAME}.zip -d /opt/ > /opt/${WSO2_FOLDER_NAME}.listfiles
RUN mv /opt/${WSO2_BUNDLE_NAME} /opt/${WSO2_FOLDER_NAME}
RUN rm /opt/${WSO2_BUNDLE_NAME}.zip

# CARPETA UBICACION SH DE DAS
WORKDIR /opt/${WSO2_FOLDER_NAME}/bin/

# SUBIMOS SERVICIOS DE DAS
CMD sh ./wso2server.sh
```